# Rolling over my 401k: Who is "New Plan Trustees of [insert name] Plan"?

Tags: united-states, 401k

On the form to initiate the rollover, I am prompted for "Name", "Rollover Account Number", and "New Plan Trustees of [blank field] Plan" (followed by address information and yadda yadda). What am I supposed to put in that field? For the sake of our example, let's say the company's name is "ABC Retirement Services" and the check needs to be payable to "ABC Trust Company".

Edit: I suppose a better question would be, "Who/what is a trustee [of a retirement plan]?

Comment: You should ask the ABC company what to put there.

Comment: You should be using the paperwork from the new company. They have a vested interest in getting it right.

Comment: The question you might want to ask yourself is whether you want to roll over existing 401k plan assets into your new employer's 401k plan, or would it be better to roll over the money into an IRA.

Comment: the issue will be the same regardless of the target: 401K, bank based IRA, Investment company IRA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should get this information from your new employer's plan manager. If they don't have this information (they should have instructions on incoming rollovers...) - talk to the benefits manager at your new employer, they'll have it for you. The name must match perfectly the official name of the plan, so asking here won't help you much.